# Modal Popups fail when initiated from thread -- CSharp WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, messagebox

To batch upload many files, there is one section of CSharp WPF code that I have which spawns threads to allow parallel uploading of files.
If an error occurs with the upload, a message would be popped up using MessageBox.  This works fine.

But now recently we've decided to customize the look of the MessageBox.  I find when our new custom WPF MessageBox window is opened with ShowDialog() that an error is thrown saying that it isn't possible to launch a GUI.  This only happens when code from the spawned thread attempts to open the custom Message window -- I don't see the problem when a custom MessageBox opens from the main thread.

My temporary fix is to catch any errors that occur when the custom dialog is launched and to alternatively call the standard MessageBox.Show() to display the message.  That works.

I'm not sure why it's OK to use the standard MessageBox.Show() but it isn't for the custom window.  Is there a way to get around this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally (in any GUI-API) don't call GUI functions from worker threads and don't do heavy work on GUI threads.
The fact that the standard MessageBox works on a worker thread is sad.

Yes, you are completely right. When on your worker thread somethings happens that needs to be displayed to the user, send a notification (signal, event, whatever your Framework calls it) to the GUI thread and display the message there.

Comment: Hyperboreus is correct.  The reason is that pretty much no UI API is built to be thread safe, so attempting to do UI tasks on the non-UI threads will typically result in hard to find threading problems.  WinForms for example has had code added to detect this and thrown an exception when you attempt to use a method of a control from the non-UI thread.  When an object is tied to a particular thread, it's said to have thread affinity.

Comment: OK -- Thanks.  But this is maybe not the answer I was hoping for :)

Answer (score 2):

```
protected void chkAll_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CheckBox chall = (CheckBox)sender;
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            CheckBox chSelect = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("ChkSelect");
            if (chSelect != null)
            {
                chSelect.Checked = chall.Checked;
            }
        }
    }
    protected void chkSelect_CheckedChange(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i=0;
        CheckBox chkAll = (CheckBox)GridView1.HeaderRow.FindControl("chkAll");
        for ( i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            CheckBox chkSelect = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("ChkSelect");
            if(chkSelect!=null && !chkSelect.Checked  )
                if (chkAll != null)
                {
                    chkAll.Checked = false;
                }
            break;
        }
        if (GridView1.Rows.Count == i && chkAll != null)
        {
            chkAll.Checked = true;
        }

    }
    protected void ddlPaymentMode_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddlpaymode = (DropDownList)sender;
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Label lblpaymode = (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("lblPayAmt_Mode");
            CheckBox chpaymode = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("ChkSelect");
            if (chpaymode.Checked)
            {
                lblpaymode.Text = ddlpaymode.SelectedItem.Text;
            }
        }
    }
    protected void ddlBankName_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DropDownList ddlBank = (DropDownList)sender;
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            CheckBox cselect = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("ChkSelect");
            Label lblBankName = (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("LblBank");
            if (cselect.Checked)
            {
                lblBankName.Text = ddlBank.SelectedItem.Text;
            }

        }
    }
    protected void btnaddbpc_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(txtChequeNo.Text);
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            CheckBox chkselect = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("ChkSelect");
            Label lblcheckno = (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("LblCheque");


            if (chkselect.Checked)
            {

                lblcheckno.Text = Convert.ToString(temp);
                temp++; 
            }

        }
    }
    protected void dtnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            CheckBox chkselect = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("ChkSelect");
            Label lblcheckno = (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("LblCheque");


            if (chkselect.Checked)
            {
                lblcheckno.Text = "";
            }

        }
    }
    protected void btnAddCDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Label lblchqdate = (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("LblCheque_Date");
            CheckBox chkselect = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("ChkSelect");
            if (chkselect.Checked)
            {
                lblchqdate.Text = TxtChequeDate.Text;
            }
        }
    }
    protected void btnRemovecDate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < GridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            Label lblchqdate = (Label)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("LblCheque_Date");
            CheckBox chkselect = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("ChkSelect");
            if (chkselect.Checked)
            {
                lblchqdate.Text = "";
            }
        }
    }
    protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.CommandName == "Modify")
        {
            string ID = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
            //Response.Redirect("Admin_Update_BinryPayment.aspx?id="+ID+"&FromDate='"+ txtfromdate.Text +"'&ToDate='"+txttilldate.Text+"'");
            int Index = ((GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).Parent.Parent).RowIndex;
            CheckBox chksec = (CheckBox)GridView1.Rows[Index].FindControl("ChkSelect");
            Label lblANo = (Label)GridView1.Rows[Index].FindControl("Label2");
            Label lbAName = (Label)GridView1.Rows[Index].FindControl("Label3");
            Label lbACName = (Label)GridView1.Rows[Index].FindControl("Label3");
            Label lbacNo = (Label)GridView1.Rows[Index].FindControl("lblBankAccountNo");
            Label lbBankName = (Label)GridView1.Rows[Index].FindControl("LblBank");
            Label lbchqNo = (Label)GridView1.Rows[Index].FindControl("LblCheque");
            Label lbchqDate = (Label)GridView1.Rows[Index].FindControl("LblCheque_Date");
            Label lblChqAmt = (Label)GridView1.Rows[Index].FindControl("Label23");
            if (chksec.Checked)
            {
                txtABNo.Text = GridView1.Rows[Index].Cells[3].Text;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, (SendOrPostCallback)delegate {
            // show your MB here
        }, null);
```